# Probability of being dealt a perfect hand in bridge

Tags: probability, card-games

Let's say a perfect hand is said to contain 13 cards all of the same suit.

What is the probability of this?

> My logic is that there are 4 possible perfect hands (all from clubs, hearts, spades, diamonds) and $52\choose13$ ways of dealing 13 card hands.
>
> This gives us $\frac4{52\choose13}$
>
> Is this logic correct?

Comment: *Assuming a perfectly random shuffle*, yes this is correct.  Be aware though that in real life, truly random shuffles do not exist and if the cards had been sorted (*for example from a fresh pack*) a few precise shuffles can guarantee that you are dealt a perfect hand, or even better yet... all players are dealt a perfect hand.  It may not have even been intentional.  See several accounts of this happening [here](https://aperiodical.com/2011/12/four-perfect-hands-an-event-never-seen-before-right/).